# Can't assign or compare packed values to unpacked values or vice versa

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, system-verilog

I am making an array and defining its values, but it shows this error:

> can't assign or compare packed values to unpacked values or vice versa

This is my code:

```
reg [31:0] mem [0:15] = {32'hAAAAAAAA, 32'h55555555, {14{32'h00000000}}};
```

I want to assign all the 16 vectors to be defined as these values.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use replication in an unpacked array concatenation.

You can use an assignment pattern with a default

```
reg [31:0] mem [0:15] = '{0:32'hAAAAAAAA, 1:32'h55555555, default:32'h00000000};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do it all in one line, but here is a way to do it in 2 lines:

```
reg [31:0] mem [0:15] = '{ 16{32'h00000000} };
initial mem[0:1] = '{32'hAAAAAAAA, 32'h55555555};
```

Initialize all array elements to the same value (0) in the declaration statement, then override the necessary elements with different values.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 10.9.1 *Array assignment patterns*.

This syntax requires you to enable SystemVerilog features in your simulator (unless already enabled by default).